# Vapor how to transform EventLoopFuture<Type> to <Type>

Tags: swift, backend, vapor, vapor-fluent

I am implementing a delete route handler using Vapor Fluent.

For this handler, I wanted to verify that the `user` sending the product deletion request is the owner of the `product`, and `Abort` the request otherwise.

```
func deleteHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPStatus> {
    let user = req.auth.get(User.self)
    return Product.find(req.parameters.get("productID"), on: req.db)
        .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
        .flatMap { product in
            return product.$user.get(on: req.db).flatMapThrowing { owner in
                guard try user?.requireID() == owner.requireID() else {
                    throw Abort(.forbidden)
                }
                return try product.delete(on: req.db)
                    .transform(to: HTTPStatus.noContent) // error here
            }
        }
}
```

But Vapor throws an error at `return try product.delete(on: req.db).transform(to: HTTPStatus.noContent)` saying `Cannot convert return expression of type 'EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponseStatus>' to return type 'HTTPStatus' (aka 'HTTPResponseStatus')`.

I tried chaining again using `map({})`, that did not help. Using `wait()`solves the error but introduces a runtime bug.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `.flatMapThrowing` isn't throwing the future. `requireID()` is overkill in this context. If you replace the `throw` as follows and remove the `Throwing` as a result, it should work:

```swift
func deleteHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPStatus> {
    let user = req.auth.get(User.self)
    return Product.find(req.parameters.get("productID"), on: req.db)
        .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
        .flatMap { product in
            return product.$user.get(on: req.db).flatMap { owner in
                guard user?.id == owner.id else {
                    return request.eventLoop.makeFailedFuture( Abort(.forbidden))
                }
                return product.delete(on: req.db)
                    .transform(to: HTTPStatus.noContent)
            }
        }
}
```

I've removed the `try` from the `delete` later on. I'm guessing the compiler didn't report this as unnecessary because of the earlier error, but it isn't usually needed. My answer will fail spectacularly if it is!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! May I ask when to use ```.id``` and when to use```requireID()```?

Comment: In this situation, you are only interested in the two `id` values being the same. The test will return false if either is missing and they can't both be nil as earlier errors would have triggered.